# O resultado da concatenação da string é extenso demais

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Fiz um select com a função `LISTAGG` para concatenar um campo da minha tabela, porem é retornado o erro:

> ORA-01489: o resultado da concatenação de string é extenso demais

## Query

```
   (SELECT LISTAGG (pf.pfnomereduzido || ' - ') within
   GROUP (
          ORDER BY pf.pfid)
   FROM fiscal cf
   LEFT JOIN pessoa pf ON pf.pfid = cf.contratofiscalpfid
   AND cf.contratofiscaldatafinal = '01/01/0001') AS contratofiscalnome
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Não conheço de Oracle, mas talvez esse exemplo possa te ajudar: [LISTAGG function: “result of string concatenation is too long”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long)

Comment: Tenta algo como: `(SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,pf.pfnomereduzido,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY pf.pfnomereduzido).GetClobVal(),',') within GROUP ( ORDER BY pf.pfid) FROM fiscal cf LEFT JOIN pessoa pf ON pf.pfid = cf.contratofiscalpfid AND cf.contratofiscaldatafinal = '01/01/0001') AS contratofiscalnome`

Comment: agora o erro mudou: palavra chave FROM não localizada onde esperada com o erro apontado para a parte within GROUP, deve ser erro de sintaxe...

Comment: Entenda esse erro como uma dica que o que você está fazendo deveria ser feito do lado cliente, não diretamente no SQL.

Comment: A solução é o caminho que o Marconi postou ... ja resolvi problemas como ele sugeriu..

Answer (score 1):

Ele tem um limite de fato , tratar distintos e reduzir o tamanho resolve às vezes,

Tente

```
 SELECT LISTAGG (V.pfnomereduzido || ' - ') within
   GROUP (
          ORDER BY pf.pfid)
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(pf.pfnomereduzido) 
         FROM fiscal cf
         LEFT JOIN pessoa pf ON pf.pfid = cf.contratofiscalpfid
         AND cf.contratofiscaldatafinal = '01/01/0001') V
```

Comment: nao teria que ter um fechamento de ) após o V?

Comment: acho que sim , não tenho como testar

Comment: desse jeito aparece: Fim inesperado do comando SQL